# CSS Background position pushes content up when screen is small

Tags: html, css, image

I have the following code:

```
<div class='row front-page-img' style="background-image:url('http://img2-3.timeinc.net/people/i/2014/news/140428/coachella-crowd-600.jpg')">
</div>
<div>Below image</div>

.front-page-img {
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height:400px;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 0.4;
    background-position: 0px -200px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I am happy with what I am seeing. That is, I like the portion the of image that I currently have. The two things that I don't like are that are the following:

- When I make the screen smaller the img gets pushed up and disappears as the screen gets small. I want it to always have the same section of the image, but just scaled down.
- For some reason there is white space below the image that is now allowing other elements to follow the image.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong and how i could fix this? Later, I would like put an input tab over this image incase that changes the approach. Thanks!

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/93nctgtb/2/)

Comment: The reason for the white space below is that you have set the image div height to be 400px so when the image doesn't fill up the whole div you get that space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use Bootstraps `img-responsive` class with an inline image. If you do not want the upper part of the image to be shown, just crop the image.

```css
@import url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css);

.front-page-img {
  opacity: .4; 
}

.front-page-img > img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="front-page-img">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="http://img2-3.timeinc.net/people/i/2014/news/140428/coachella-crowd-600.jpg" />
</div>

<div>Below image</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Cropping the image makes everything so much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Update your CSS to the following.

```
.front-page-img {
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height:0;
    padding-bottom:40%;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 0.4;
    /* background-position: 0px -200px; */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

By setting the height to 0, we can use padding-bottom to maintain a fixed ratio as when you use percentage based padding it is relevant to the element width.

Comment: Image still disappears when there is a smaller screen.

Comment: This is because of the `background-position` you have here. If you remove this it will not disappear. Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
.front-page-img {
background-size:cover;
height:400px;
opacity: 0.4;
background-position: 0px -200px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

}

Comment: Still leaves a gap between the next element and image.

Comment: Well you are using the hard-coded height dimension. You could either use the bootstrap or you can write different css based on the size of a particular screen.

Answer (score 0):

This works better for what you want.

```
background-position: center  bottom;
```

Comment: I changed this incase you want the top of image off page. This should give  the desired result.